# Pixi.js WebGL renderer polygon artifact

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to implement lasso tool for selection in javascript but when drawing the lasso as a polygon (a filled path made of points), I get some artifacts looking like some rays that are not very nice. In the picture below they are in the area over/under the red lines (those were drawn in mspaint).

[image]

I'm using graphics library Pixi.js for drawing polygon but I believe this is canvas related as the basic series of drawing commands like `moveTo->lineTo->lineTo->lineTo` create the same artifact (the shape is only defined by points in the red area, the rest of the blue line is artifact).

[image]

Is there any way to prevent these from occurring?

**EDIT:** The problem might not be the HTML5 canvas but WebGL and/or Pixi.js engine. I'll also probably create an issue on their GitHub if this is confirmed not to be my error.

**EDIT2:** I have assembled a minimum complete example. As there is no CDN for Pixi, I had to host it temporarily [here](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xsevci50/Pixi/index.html). I'm developing in typescript but it shouldn't make difference. This is the code that draws the bad geometry (full source [here](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xsevci50/Pixi/src/ts/Drawing/Canvas.ts)):

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x0000FF);
graphics.moveTo(100,300);
graphics.lineTo(170,100);
graphics.lineTo(165,98);
graphics.lineTo(100,300);
this.container.addChild(graphics);

graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0x0);
graphics.drawCircle(100,300,2);
graphics.drawCircle(170,100,2);
graphics.drawCircle(165,98,2);
graphics.endFill();
this.container.addChild(graphics);
```

The first part renders the geometry with artifact, second is only to show where the points actually are. The renderer is WebGL. Pixi version 3.0.7.

Comment: Can you post a [complete example](http://sscce.org), including actual code?

Comment: jsfiddle would be a plus.

Comment: I'll try to prepare jsfiddle for the second case in a moment.

Comment: Do you know when the artifacts are created? I don't use pixi.js and I haven't had this problem.

Comment: My guess just by the looks of it is that pixi.js is trying to close the polygon or there's a problem in your code or pixi.js code

Comment: The first artifact is created when 2 successive points in lasso path have nearly the same Y coordinate. With the second I'm not really sure. In the jsfiddle I created (http://jsfiddle.net/3pf1L038/) it really does work when drawing manually to the context. However, I now realized that the renderer is set to WebGL by default so the issue might be either the WebGL itself or Pixi. Question updated.

Comment: @phihag See edit2 for complete example.

Comment: There is a Pixi CDN here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pixi.js

Comment: @Karmacon oh, my apologies, really couldn't find it at that moment.

Comment: @Raven np. that was just an FYI